# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to run the code below in Python 3 and I keep getting the error

> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 407: Proxy Authentication Required

**Code:**

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json

serviceurl = ''

while True:
    address =input('Enter location: ')
    if len(address) < 1 : break

    #add the parameters needed to the url
    url = serviceurl + urllib.parse.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address': address})

    uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()

    js = json.loads(str(data))

    #extract place_id
    place_id = js["results"][0]['place_id']
    print (place_id)
```

Why am I getting this error ?

Comment: Hi,@ abhishek-shegde pls add what you want to achieve or do you just want to remove the error ?

Comment: @Gino Mempin- Thanks for replying. this code is to prompt for a location ,contact web service and retrieve Json for the web service and parse that data.